# Extjs 4.1.1 combobox not returning numeric value

Tags: extjs4.1

Extjs 4.1.1 xtype: 'combo' not returning the value after submitting the form.

I have an array like `user = ['user1','user2',...]` and I need a dropdown in form panel. After submitting the form I found that the key values of the arrays are not submitted, rather the displayFields are submitted instead.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more code for us to help you.  This sounds like a misunderstanding of how a combobox works, but I can't be sure without a better example of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue as below :

var comboVal = Ext.getCmp('combo_id').getValue();
var record = Ext.getCmp('combo_id').findRecord(Ext.getCmp('combo_id').displayField, comboVal); 
var ComboIDValue = record.get('comboVal');

ComboIDValue  is the key value of combo